# How to remove a substring from text and assign a nested substring to a variable?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I'm working in Joomla developing a Module where I need to strip this snippet from the `$article->text` and extract the part number to have its contents stored in `$part_number`.

```
{myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}
```

I've been trying to work something out, but I can't get it working:

```
$re = '/\{myplugin\}(\w+),[^{}]+\{\/myplugin\}/';

$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $article->text);
$article->text = $result;
```

But this doesn't return the part number so I can put it in `$part_number`. Can this be done in one regular expression operation, or should it be one to extract the number number and a second to remove the snippet from `$article->text`?

The intention is to have `{myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}` removed from `$article->text` and have its part number such as `ABCDEF1234` copied from this snippet and stored in PHP variable `$part_number`.

Comment: Please write out your expected result in your question.

Comment: @mickmackusa Done.

Comment: You need alphanumeric from the `string`, right?

Comment: @MUT Yes, alphanumeric.

Comment: try `\b[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+\b`, hope this work in your code.

Comment: Might there be multiple plugin substrings to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `preg_match`:

```
$s='{myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}';
preg_match('/{myplugin}(\w+)\,"(.+)"{\/myplugin}/', $s, $result);
```

`$result` will be:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '{myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}' (length=48)
  1 => string 'ABCDEF1234' (length=10)
  2 => string 'Flux Capacitor' (length=14)
```

UPD:

```
$article->text = str_replace($result[0], '', $article->text);
$part_number = $result[1];
```

Comment: @mickmackusa using `$result` array he can remove this string form text by `str_replace` (using `$result[0]`) and get part number from `$result[1]`.

Comment: @mickmackusa please show where there is mentioning about `one call`?

Comment: Fyi, your answer will not match properly if 2 plugin tags exist in the same line.  But this may be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: The OP does ask: _Can this be done in one regular expression operation_  which I interpret as one step, while your method uses one regex call then a separate non-regex replacement call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can remove the plugin substring from `$article->text` AND declare `$partnumber` in one hit.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f7d776d0fd52ba2af209655b46ec28696239774))

```
$article=(object)['text'=>'Some leading text {myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin} some trailing text'];
$re = '~\{myplugin\}([^,]+),[^{]+\{/myplugin\}~';
$subst = '';

$article->text=preg_replace_callback($re,function($m)use(&$partnumber){ $partnumber=$m[1]; return '';},$article->text,1);

echo $article->text;
echo "\n";
echo $partnumber;
```

Output:

```
Some leading text  some trailing text
ABCDEF1234
```

By switching from `preg_replace()` to `preg_replace_callback()` you can call an anonymous function to carry out the two tasks. First, the new variable `$partnumber` is declared, then the empty string replaces the greater plugin substring (fullstring match).

`use(&$partnumber)` allows you to declare a modifiable variable inside the callback function which will be available in the global scope.

My method assumes that there will only ever be **1** found `$partnumber` (this is why there is a `1` for a value in the 4th parameter.  If there are two or more, then the 4th parameter must be removed and the `$partnumber` assignment must be written as an array `$partnumber[]=$m[1]` so that earlier matches aren't overwritten by later ones.

Comment: @EdwardCoast Am I misunderstanding the task?

Comment: You understand fine. You have the $subst in there, but aren't using it. What part of your code is removing the snippet?

Comment: Do you see that the plugin is gone in the output?  That's what you asked for right?  It would be clearer for me if you presented a fuller, more realistic string for `$article-text`.

Comment: @mickmacusa Yes, I see that. I'm asking what specific part of your PHP code was able to do that. Your demo data for $article->text was fine.

Comment: @EdwardCoast is my explanation sufficient for you? Or is there more that you would like me to explain?  Will you be awarding the green tick for this page?

Comment: @EdwardCoast did my single function call confuse you?  This is a professional grade answer.